# Shortcut to check out revision for Git in WebStorm/IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I've found that I can quickly open a commit log with Alt-9 and move through commits with the arrow keys. However, I can't find any other keyboard shortcuts for the log menu. In particular, one a version is selected, how do you check it out with a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: There is no shortcut and this action is not available in Keymap, [submit a request to make it configurable](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA).

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks for the confirmation, submitting one now.